# Variables values in remotely executed complex bash commands

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to run a complex list of commands on a remote host. I could solve easily by creating another script with such commands and then have my other script call it (with or without copying it to the remote host), but I do not want to. My issue is that I have some variables that are fixed for the whole script and then I have the for-loop variable. I can get one of the two to be properly evaluated on the remote host, but noth both. All I've found on similar issues is talks about using note quotes, " or ' around different elements. **Nothing I've tried worked on both the fixed (to be expanded before ssh) and the loop variables (to be expanded remotely) at the same time** (highlight for you, @Inian, since you can't fucking read the full question before marking it as duplicate of something it's not a duplicate of).

```sh
fixed_value="blue"

ssh remote_host << "EOF"
    value_list="VALUE1 VALUE2"
    for i in $value_list; do
        echo "executing $i"
        my_program -arg1 $i -arg2 "$fixed_value"
    done
EOF
```

What I expect is to run my_program (which is a binary on the remote host) with two arguments, one is fixed and is actually passed as an input to the local script, the other is read from a list of fixed values, so that, in the example, I should end up executing on remote host the following:

```sh
my_program -arg1 VALUE1 -arg2 blue
my_program -arg1 VALUE2 -arg2 blue
```

I probably need a way to 'pass values' to the script being executed in the remote host, or force evaluation of $fixed_value before the command is sent (which I tried to do by using quotes, but it didn't work), without preventing the evaluation of $i from being done on the remote host. Because all I get by switching around the quotes (or removing them, or changing them) is either:

```sh
my_program -arg1 -arg2 blue
my_program -arg1 -arg2 blue
```

or

```sh
my_program -arg1 VALUE1 -arg2
my_program -arg1 VALUE2 -arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

Restructured:

```
fixed_value="blue"
value_list=( VALUE1 VALUE2 )
for i in "${value_list[@]}"; do
    echo "executing $i"
    ssh remote_host "my_program -arg1 $i -arg2 $fixed_value"
done
```

If you really want this to all be done in a single call, then write it as a script, `scp` it over, then `ssh` to call it on the target machine.

...or write it locally to a temp file :

```
$: cat a
echo '
fixed_value="blue"
value_list=( VALUE1 VALUE2 )
for i in "${value_list[@]}"; do
    echo "executing $i"
    echo "my_program -arg1 $i -arg2 $fixed_value"
done
'>/tmp/foo && . /tmp/foo && rm /tmp/foo
```

and then run it as

```
ssh remote_host < a
```

which produces:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
executing VALUE1
my_program -arg1 VALUE1 -arg2 blue
executing VALUE2
my_program -arg1 VALUE2 -arg2 blue
```

Comment: Thanks but, as I mentioned in the first line of my post, I don't want to create a second file. I'm not disagreeing with the maintainability aspect. I'm merging my scripts for my colleagues, as they are a temporary workaround for lack of certain tools (currently in development). Since the intended users are people with very limited CS knowledge a single file makes it easier for them (and since it will be soon thrown away, mainteinance is a non issue).

Comment: Regarding your solution, I had considered this approach, but it seemed to me to be cleaner to just connect once and do everything needed, rather than repeatedly opening and closing connections. Not that it would matter in this specific script, but if the loop were to be over thousands of items maybe the sysadmins would get mad at me? I don't know for sure, so I wanted to play it in a safer way.

Comment: lol.. yeah, I thought about the temp file too. I wanted to see if it was possible to have a 'clean' way to send the 'complex' command via ssh from within the script. I was not looking for workarounds, I was hoping to learn a very specific bash scripting detail. Still, thanks for the effort. I've worked around the issue changing the syntax to an ssh -t <host> "command".

Comment: Another approach: `echo 'big; command; complex;'|ssh ...` That just costs you some quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

fixed_value="blue"
qq='"'

ssh remote_host bash -c "
  value_list='VALUE1 VALUE2'
  for i in \$value_list; do
    echo ${qq}executing \$i$qq
    my_program -arg1 \$i -arg2 '$fixed_value'
  done
"
```

I've wrapped the command in a `bash -c "…"` command. Because you still need some double-quotes and because I've come to distrust escaped quotes, I created a `$qq` variable to represent the double-quote character. Variables passed from the server side (`$qq` and `$fixed_value`) are unescaped so their values are passed to the server. Variables for server-side evaluation (`$value_list` and `$i`) are escaped so they are interpreted by the remote bash call.

The exit code of this client-side script will be the exit code from `ssh`, which should be dictated by the exit code from the final iteration of `my_program` (unless `ssh` itself fails or is terminated).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be honest I didn't specify it but I was trying to avoid the single string syntax as that looked more appropriate for short commands. Still, I've gone for this approach. The only thing, for some reason bash -c always complained about lack of argument, so I settled for 'ssh -t remote_host "commands"'

Comment: If you do e.g. `ssh -t remote_host "ls 123"` then it'll try to execute `"ls 123"` too literally and bash will give you `ls 123: command not found`. Using `sh -c` or `bash -c` will let you specify commands with proper spacing.

Comment: @AdamKatz, I'm not seeing that problem. The remote command receives the quoted string for `ssh -t remote_host "ls 123"`, but not the quotes... I kinda like your embedded quote solution, though.