# Bash scripting with heredocs or better approach

Tags: python, bash, ssh, heredoc

I need to run some commands inside

```
ssh->ssh->clientprogram->loop command
```

Here are my requirements to execute commands.

1. Send input argument to the first ssh server, capture the output of that command (which is a bash script inter-dependent on other scripts within the same path and available in $path variable. I did check with echo $PATH)
2. Provide step1 command output which is ***ip*** to second ssh command.
3. loop it for n times and inside the loop, enable the client and execute series of commands and capture the output of both commands and verify the output from second command (Ex: series of commands are : rm file ; ls -> check the file exists or not and then repeat same until n iterations)
4. Step3 should be executed based on the choice (ex: create file or delete file). This variable should be option from the user at the beginning.

As of now I am able to put all static IPs and able to execute one command

```
 ssh_to_server () {

        remote_output=$(ssh -t root@10.25.55.10 << "EOF"
            # looking for command to capture output of input entry 1 and proceed further like
           command_output=$(/tmp/user/script $1) # this is not working. getting file or directory not found.
            ssh -t user@10.50.10.76 << "EOF1"
                clientprogram <<-"EOF2"
                  loop;then
                    command1  # based on "option"
                     command2  # checking if the delete or create operation is success.
                  end loop
                  /exit . # exit from the client program
                EOF2
            EOF1
    EOF)
    }
ssh_to_server "input" "option"
```

Sample IPs in the above code.

I am able to execute the command inside client program and capture the output but what I need is:

1. capture the ip output from the command in first ssh server and pass it dynamically to second ssh server.

   2. pass option from user to the client program or second server to create or delete files.

Note: Second ssh server doesn't allow ssh from any other ip except from first server. So, ssh tunnel and other's won't work. If there is any better way to handle using other scripting language (Python, Perl) or Java (I can create a jar) is acceptable.

Comment: there shouldn't be spaces around `=`, it should have been `command_output=$(/tmp/user/script $1)`

Comment: Look into running ssh with a proxy command. That is the normal way to deal with ssh jump hosts.

Comment: Also, regarding the part that is not working. On which host do you expect to run `/tmp/user/script`? On your localhost or on the jump host?

Comment: on the first host

Comment: Inian, i fixed the spaces between the command output and the command.

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen, i don't know the ip of the second server until i execute the command on the first server.

Comment: @user2503849, not knowing that IP up-front doesn't stop you from using the OpenSSH JumpHost option, though it does mean that if you want it to be efficient, you might also use `ControlMaster`/`ControlSocket` to reuse the same Transport for both the initial channel running the command that collects the IP and the second one running a tunneled ssh to the destination.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I am new to bash scripting. Can you please provide one example for the Controlmaster/controlsocket program.

Comment: BTW, note that ideally, different parts of this would be asked as separate questions. Passing command-line arguments through a SSH connection is a quite separate topic than tunneling through a dynamically-determined jumphost.

Comment: This appears highly related to [Variables values in remotely executed complex bash commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56360105/519360) but I'm not sure it's a full duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### With Two Separate Transports

The easy way to do this is as two separate steps, as in:

```
printf -v args_q '%q ' "$@"  # store our script's arguments in a string
host2_ip=$(ssh host1 get_host2_ip)
ssh -o"ProxyJump host1" "$host2_ip" "bash -s $args_q" <<'EOF'
  ...inner command for host2 goes here...
EOF
```

Because of the `-o"ProxyJump host1"`, the connection to `host2_ip` is made from `host1`; however, the host2_ip is returned back to the system running the script first.

---

#### With One Transport

If you need more performance than that, that's when `ControlSocket` functionality comes in.

```
printf -v args_q '%q ' "$@"  # store our script's arguments in a string
ssh_common_args=( -o"ControlMaster=yes" -o"ControlPath $HOME/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p" )
host2_ip=$(ssh "${ssh_common_args[@]}" host1 get_host2_ip)
ssh "${ssh_common_args[@]}" -o"ProxyJump host1" "$host2_ip" "bash -s $args_q" <<'EOF'
  ...inner command for host2 goes here...
EOF
```

This way, the same connection is used for *both* channel invocations on `host1` -- the first connection used to retrieve the host2 IP address, and the second one used to run your actual remote command.

Comment: but the second host accepts ssh only from the first host. Will this work with this condition. Also how can i work on the output of the commands inside the client program. like filtering the output of first command and decide to execute other commands.

Comment: As for capturing content, that's what the command substitutions are for -- see `host2_ip=$(...)`? That puts content in a variable named `host2_ip` back on the host where you can inspect and modify it.

Comment: You can similarly capture the output of your larger command with `host2_result=$(ssh ...` on the last command; add the closing `)` on a separate line, after the `EOF`.

Comment: i tried with your 2 steps script, with this i am able to get the second host ip and when i am trying that with the second command it is throwing me permission denied with msg " Permission denied (publickey).". Can you please let me know what might be the issue. Just to add, i don't have  the keys for the second server as it is a locked down server and allows only from server or host1. Please let me know if it is clear for you or i will try to explain more.

Comment: Umm. If you have permission to log into host1, and host1 contains a plaintext key for host2, you have all the access you need to steal^W^W^W^Wgrab that key and copy it back to your original system, unless the maintainers of host1 are doing something atypically clever (like running a locked-down local SSH agent).

Comment: ...that's not a *firewall* issue, though, it's an *authentication* issue. The connection is being properly routed through host1, but you still need to have the ability to authenticate to host2 before your SSH daemon can connect to it.

Comment: Frankly, the people running host2 shouldn't be doing it that way -- leaving credentials in plaintext *anywhere* is a great way to get them stolen; using a shared account, moreover, means they get stolen *and then you can't tell who was involved in the breach*. Instead of giving host1 credentials to host2, they should be installing the credentials of authorized users (like you!) directly on host2.

Comment: ...anyhow, to connect through to host2 using the existing infrastructure without giving your security analyst too much of a heartache, consider running a local SSH agent, and adding the key on host1 to that agent's store before you try to connect to host2. After doing the work of setting up and starting `ssh-agent` on the system where your script runs, that *may* (but may not, lots of local configuration details involved) be as simple as `ssh host1 ssh-add`.

Comment: I am able to achieve with my script and i will keep this for future scripting projects. I will give bounty for the answer.